# Auto refresh python httpserver when a file is updated

Tags: python, http, xampp, webserver, refresh

I am making a file hoster sorta thing (like xampp) using python and its http library and
heres da code

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time, os

def start_server(hostName="localhost", serverPort=8080):
    class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            if os.path.exists("./htdocs/index.html"):
                self.wfile.write(bytes(open("./htdocs/index.html").read(), "utf-8"))

    if serverPort:        
        webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
        print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

        try:
            webServer.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

        webServer.server_close()
        print("Server stopped.")
```

is there a way to check that a file is changed (or updated) so I can autorefresh the page so it becomes a LIVE SERVER???